# Manually converting CSS to LESS, using extend

Tags: css, less, extend

I've recently started to use LESS and am trying to convert my CSS to LESS for a project.

I'm trying to get `li.active > a, li > a:hover` working

```
#sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px;
  text-align: right;

  li {
    & > a {
      color: #999;

      &:hover {
        //&:extend(.active > a);
        color: #FFF;
        background: none;
      }
    }

    &.active > a:extend(& > a:hover) {}
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work.
I'm looking at the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) but it's not really making sense to me.

**EDIT:**

Found out that this works

```
#sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px 10px 10px;
  text-align: right;

  li {
    & > a {
      color: #999;

      &:hover {
        color: #FFF;
        background: none;
      }
    }

    &.active > a {
      &:extend(#sidenav li > a:hover);
    }
  }
}
```

But that's 3 lines where I think it could be 1.

Comment: Does `&.active > a:extend(#sidenav li > a:hover) {}` work? Or just `&.active > a { &:extend(#sidenav li > a:hover); }` if you want only 1 line

Comment: You can do `li.active > a:extend(#sidenav li > a:hover){}` outside the `li{}`.

Comment: And just in case, are you sure a plain more CSS-like construction ([e.g.](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/74d90c569bbeb507b44f#file-24806790-less)) is not less cryptic in this case?